# ~ operator in C

Tags: c, operators

The output of this program is -13. I have never fully understood ~ operator in C. Why does it give -13 as output? How to limit ~ operator to just 4 bits of a number?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int a = 12;
        a = ~a;
        printf("%d",a);
        getch();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Read C99 6.5.33, **Unary arithmetic operators**. "The result of the ~ operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that type minus E." The part about integer promotions will take you to C99 6.3.1.1, and it is a little heady, but you asked.

Comment: You get -13 because the system uses the two's complement for negative numbers while the `~` operator gives you the one's complement. The two's complement is defined as the one's complement plus one.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bitwise operator (one's complement ) that works this way :

```
~00000101 // 5
=11111010 // 250
```

so the 1s become 0s and vise versa but in some cases the sign bit is activated and you'll get unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

To limit the effect to a specified number of bits, just use bitwise masks, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 16;             /* 10000 in binary */
    int b = ~a;             /* Will interpret b as -17 in two's complement */
    int c = (a & ~0xF) | (~a & 0xF); /* Will limit operator to rightmost 4 bits,
                                        so 00000 becomes 01111, and c will become
                                        11111, not 11...101111, so c will be 31     */

    printf("a is %d, b is %d, c is %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./comp
a is 16, b is -17, c is 31
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

Comment: You are so close. But, you will need to clear out the right most four bits before you do `a | (~a & 0xF)` . Reason it worked for you is, you are having `a` as `16` which in binary is `10000`. Run your program with `a` as `17` which in binary is `10001`, and you will still the see the output as `31`

Answer (score 1):

`(12)10` in binary is `(1100)2`

The tilde is the bitwise complement operator which makes `1100` --> `0011`. However if you working on a 32 bit platform actually what we get is:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100
```

Whose bitwise complement is:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0011
|
```

Now since the left most bit is for sign the number becomes negative. If you use unsigned int you will be able to understand better what is happening:

```
unsigned int a = 12;
a = ~a;
```

Will give:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0011
```

Which is `4294967283`

Answer (score 1):

The operator `~` is the logical `not` in C, i.e. when applied to a integer it flips every single it of its binary representation. Note that defining a integer in simply as `int` makes it unsigned integer. That means that the first it is used as a sign bit. Since negatives are defines as `-a = ~a + 1` you can see that `~a = -a - 1`. If you want to flip only the last 4(or more generally the last k) bit of a `int` you could do something like this

```
int k = 4;
int mask = (1 << k) - 1;
int b = a ^ mask;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ~ operator acts as a binary NOT, that is, it flips all the bits in the number. Negative numbers in signed integers are stored as [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).